# SOAP UI passing in a form a list of long

Tags: java, rest, soapui

I have to check a GET method (REST) which takes a list of longs as a parameter. What should I insert in the corresponding SOAP-UI form in order to run the method?
For example if the parameter was a String, all I had to do was inserting a the string in the form.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Servlet API, all request parameters are Strings, so you don't have many choices. The conversion of those Strings to the type you need for your business logic methods, depends on the MVC framework you're using (or your own code in case you don't use any framework).

In short: The GET method will only send Strings as parameters. It's up to your application to treat those Strings as longs.